# Error upload file: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.- API GOOGLE DRIVE

Tags: c#

Tengo un error que no sé como solucionar con el API de Google Drive. Lo que estoy probando es subir un archivo desde .net core, este es mi código.

```
DriveService service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credenciales,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });
            var fileMetadata = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File()
            {
                Name = Path.GetFileName(direccion),                
                Parents = new List<string> { FolderId }
            };
            String contentType = "image/jpeg";                
            FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request;
            using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream("File/prueba.jpg",
                                    System.IO.FileMode.Open))
            {
                request = service.Files.Create(
                    fileMetadata, stream, contentType);
                request.Fields = "id";
                request.Upload();
            }
            var file = request.ResponseBody;
            var file_id = file.Id;
```

Pero me sale este error

> Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Me devuelve `NULL` en `request.ResponseBody`. Lo que yo necesito es el id del archivo que he subido, pero no me lo devuelve.

He seguido la [documentación oficial](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads).

Comment: Hola amigo, la documentación oficial siguiere que la instancia del archivo sea `var fileMetadata = new File()`, no `var fileMetadata = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File()`

Comment: Marca como error si dejo el "new File()" , y lo único que coincide con los datos que le siguen es la referencia del [...].Data.file() porque también hay sugerencia de System.IO pero no tiene los parámetros que le siguen...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré la solución, era algo tan sencillo como los permisos. Asegúrese de tener los Scopes de la siguiente forma

```
 static string[] Scopes = new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive };
```

Quickstart .NET declara `DriveService.Scope.DriveReadonly` por lo que no está dando permisos más que los de lectura. En caso que se haya autenticado borre la carpeta que se crea con el token y autentiquese nuevamente. En caso de la documentación lo nombra como **token.json** que será el nombre de la carpeta. Eso resuelve el problema.

Comment: Marca la respuesta como aceptada mediante un click en el check verde del costado :D